# BE pronunciation question

Tags: pronunciation

Recently I have been trying to improve my pronunciation and I have made a huge progress. I learn British English in school and that's why I learnt to pronounce words the Standard British way. What I don't know is whether it is correct to do so given that I am a rhotic speaker. Would it be considered strange to speak Standard British English, but with a rhotic accent? Would this be a strange mix?

Comment: This question is obscure enough that I expect some edits are necessary. If the question is whether the English can understand rhotic English, the answer is that Americans and Irish visitors to England do not need translators. If the question is whether you will be mistaken for a native speaker of Received British English if you ignore **any** of its primary distinguishing features, the question answers itself. The number of varieties of English spoken in the British Isles suggests to me that there is great tolerance for differences in English there, but that is a cultural question.

Answer (score 1):

Many English regional accents are rhotic, even when spoken by educated individuals. Received Pronunciation (RP) ("BBC English") is non-rhotic but to sound your Rs would not be considered strange.